# Lists comparison in loop: print second tuple element if condition

Tags: python

I have the following list and nested list:

```
first_var = ["id1","id2","id3"]
second_var = [("id1","name1"),("id2","name2"),("id3","name3"),("id4","name4"),]
```

I want to check for each first element in 'second_var' that doesn't exist in 'first_var' and print the second element in the 'second_var'.

my code is:

```
for x in [x[0] for x in second_var]:
    if x not in first_var:
        print(...)
```

For now if i execute `print(x)` it prints:

`id4`

but i need it to print
`name4`

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a set for first_var and a dict for second_var? Would probably have some performance improvements.

Comment: `for id, name in second_var: ... print(name)`

Comment: @Ahmad, it's working for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are not iterating the original list. You are only iterating the first entry of each tuple within the list.

This is how you can adapt your code:

```
first_var = ["id1","id2","id3"]
second_var = [("id1","name1"),("id2","name2"),("id3","name3"),("id4","name4"),]

for x in second_var:
    if x[0] not in first_var:
        print(x[1])
```

The Pythonic solution is to convert this to a list comprehension:

```
values = set(first_var)
res = [x[1] for x in second_var if x[0] not in values]

for item in res:
    print(item)
```

Or the functional version; not recommended, but another way of seeing the logic:

```
from operator import itemgetter

values = set(first_var)
res = map(itemgetter(1), filter(lambda x: x[0] not in values, second_var))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list comprehension` feature.

```
ids = [tuple[1] for tuple in second_var if tuple[0] not in first_var]
print(ids)
```

Output

```
['name4']
```

The list comprehension statement above is equivalent to:

```
>>> result = []
   for tuple in second_var:
      if tuple[0] not in first_var:
         result.append(tuple[1])

>>> result
['name4']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [v[1] for v in second_var if v[0] not in first_var]
['name4']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of data, you need to build a dictionary & use `set` & all those nice hashing/difference techniques already existing in Python instead of linear lookup in lists (`O(1)` vs `O(n)`).

```
first_var = ["id1","id2","id3"]
second_var = [("id1","name1"),("id2","name2"),("id3","name3"),("id4","name4"),]

second_d = dict(second_var)  # create a dict directly from tuples

missing = set(second_d).difference(first_var)
for m in missing:
    print(second_d[m])
```

this prints `name4`

`missing` is the difference between the dict keys and the list.